# StencilJS Unable to test timeout execution on connectedCallback

Tags: jestjs, web-component, stenciljs

I'm building a notification toast which will disappear after given time, the time (ms) is passed into `Prop() timeout`. It works as expected but i'm not able to test this. I'm expecting the `setAnimation` function to be called after the timeout execution. This is the definition of the class:

```
export class Notification {
  @Element() host: HTMLElement;
  @Prop() timeout: number = 0; //default value
  @State() animation: string = "in";

  connectedCallback() {
    if (this.timeout) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setAnimation("out");
      }, this.timeout);
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
  setAnimation(animationName: string) {
   //"out" animation is defined with keyframes in the scss file
   this.animation = animationName;
  }
}
```

The test (jest):

```
  it('setAnimation is called when timeout is provided to notification', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [Notification],
      template: () => <notification timeout={1000}></notification>,
    });
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        const notif = page.rootInstance;
        const setAnimationSpy = jest.spyOn(notif, "setAnimation");
        expect(page.rootInstance.animation).toEqual("in");
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
        jest.runAllTimers();
        expect(page.rootInstance.animation).toEqual("out");

        jest.useRealTimers();
        expect(setAnimationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //fails
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`jest.useFakeTimers()` is used after component render (connectedCallback), so real timers getting used in the test.

Moving that line to start of the test fixes the test